# How to deploy WP8 application on device with update existing application (incremental installation over existing app)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, incremental-build

I have create one Windows Phone project with Windows Phone 8 Template.

If i deploy for first time in device then it showing following log in VS output window:

- Connecting to Device...
- Optimizing for device...
- Installing the application...
- Updating information related to installed files...

this works fine. now i am updating some data in local db (sqlite database) of the apps and again i clean the solution and rebuild the app it is showing following log in VS output window:

- Connecting to Device...
- Optimizing for device...
- The application is already installed on the device. Checking if an
  incremental deployment is possible...
- Doing full deployment as project was cleaned and rebuilt...
- **Uninstalling the application...**
- Installing the application...
- Updating information related to installed files...

and this recent installation is overwrite my existing app data (sqlite db data) but i don't want to "*Uninstalling the application...*". I have only update the app. 
**I don't want to uninstall the app before update.**

**can you please let me know what was the issue. and how do i maintain existing data database and local cache while updating the new app with few updates.**

I am using Visual Studio 2013, Project Type: Windows Phone, Template: Windows Phone App.

Any help/suggestion/comments would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't rebuild or clean your project, then deployment wont reinstall the app. I am afraid that with rebuild it is not possible to preserve app data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Can you please help me for how to handle app upgrade with preserving local cache and sqlite db to overwritten from new?

Comment: Just don't Clean or Rebuild your Solution. Simply make the changes you want and tell Visual Studio to run it.
If I understood your question correctly that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Do not clean or rebuild the solution. Just build and deploy the app after making changes. It will update your app and keep previous data in IsolatedStorage.
If that is not possible, you can use IsolatedStoargeExplorer tool. Take a snapshot of your IsolatedStorage before installing the update. Then after installing the update, replace the IsolatedStorage content with the backed up data.
You can take the backup as:
`ISETool.exe ts <xd|de> <product-id> <desktop-path>`
and then replace it as
`ISETool.exe rs <xd|de> <product-id> <desktop-path>`
More information: http://goo.gl/zKbw9Z